# How to check checkbox in stimulsoft

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I have a Boolean field in database, it is used for condition of sale, if that field was true it means cash else it means credit card, now I want checked cash or credit in my report but I don't know how it's possible

How can I check it in stimulsoft?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I solved my problem
I set two condition for that checkbox, one if true and one if false

If it was false my checkbox doesn't show and if it was true checkbox shows in report.

But I have one another problem, when we make one report and we want make report again from another row it wasn't reload and I solved this problem again

Thanks